# Laravel 4 - foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel

I have the following relations:

Discount:

```
<?php
    class Discount extends Eloquent {
        protected $table = 'discount';
        public $timestamps = true;

        public function title()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('Translation', 'labelId', 'titleLabelId')->where('languageId', T::getLang())->first()['phrase'];
        }

        public function titles()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Translation', 'labelId', 'titleLabelId');
        }

    }
?>
```

Translation:

```
 <?php
        class Translation extends Eloquent {
            protected $table = 'translations';
            public $timestamps = false;

            protected $fillable = array('phrase', 'languageId', 'labelId');

            public function language()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo('Language', 'languageId');
            }

            public function label()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo('Label', 'labelId');
            }


}
?>
```

Label:

```
<?php
    class Label extends Eloquent {
        protected $table = 'label';
        public $timestamps = false;

        protected $fillable = array('key');

        public function translations()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Translation', 'labelId', 'id');
        }
    }
?>
```

There are three database tables with the following columns:

Discount:

id | titleLabelId

Translation:

id | languageId | labelId

Label:

id

**The problem:** I'd like to create a title (translation) and associate it with the discount. Here's what I've tried:

```
$discount = new Discount;

   /*create a new label*/

   $labelKey = Label::max('key') + 1;
   $label = new Label(array('key' => $labelKey));
   $label->save();

   /*create a new title (and associate it with the label)*/

   $title = new Translation(
   array(
    'phrase' => $input['title'],
    'languageId' => 3,
    'labelId' => $label->id
   ));

   $title->save();

   $discount->save();

   $discount->titles()->save($title);
```

Apparently, the `$discount->titles()->save($title);` part doesn't work. The title is only attached to the discount if I do it manually: `$discount->titleLabelId = $label->id`. Is there a way to do it using the ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Discount Model, do you have your relationship set up to use the proper table and foreign key?

```
class Discount extends Eloquent
{
    public function titles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Translation', 'translations', 'titleLabelId');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer put me on the right track. My relationship now looks like this: `return $this->belongsTo('Translation', 'titleLabelId', 'labelId');` Because of this, I can now use `$discount->titles()->associate($title);` to associate the title with the translations.

Comment: Although it does seem strange that a discount belongs to a title translation (common sense dictates the reverse situation).

Answer (score 1):

When trying to associate one model with another through a defined relationship in Eloquent, you should use the `associate()` method rather than the `save()` method.

`$discount->titles()->associate($title);`

Before this happens though, you should be sure to call the `save()` method on anything that has been altered or is new.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit and explain how this code is supposed to help?